# Apache Geode CacheServerException Region not found during key set request

Tags: gemfire, geode

I am new to Geode, and have started the default `locator` and `server` according to [Geode in 5 minutes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutesGeodein5minutes) and then the .Net client with which I am running the tests from [here](https://gemfire-native.docs.pivotal.io/geode/dotnet-caching-api/simple-csharp-example.html)

```
// 1. Create a cache
CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheFactory.CreateCacheFactory();
Cache cache = cacheFactory.Create();

// 2. Create default region attributes using region factory
RegionFactory regionFactory =
    cache.CreateRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);

// 3. Create a region
IRegion<int, string> region =
    regionFactory.Create<int, string>("exampleRegion");

// 4. Put some entries
region[111] = "Value1";
region[123] = "123";

// 5. Get the entries
string result1 = region[111];
string result2 = region[123];

// 6. Close cache
cache.Close();

// 7. Print result
Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

and when it comes to step 4, to put some entries into the region, it's giving out the error:

```
Apache.Geode.Client.CacheServerException : Region::serverKeys: CacheableString( org.apache.geode.cache.RegionDestroyedException: Server connection from [identity(0.0.0.0(default_GeodeDS:6420:loner):2:GFNative_qxrXVNzVzR6420:default_GeodeDS,connection=1; port=55687]: Region named /exampleRegion was not found during key set request
```

Both the .Net client and the server are running on the same machine. Why isn't the client finding the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that the server couldn't find the region, not that the client couldn't connect to the server: `Region named /exampleRegion was not found during key set request`. Have you defined the `exampleRegion` on the server side?.

If you're using the [Cluster Configuration Service](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_persist.html) the easiest way to do so is through the [GFSH](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/tools_modules/gfsh/chapter_overview.html) commands, namely [create region](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863): `gfsh create region --name=exampleRegion --type=REPLICATE`.

If you're configuring your members individually using the [cache.xml file](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/reference/topics/chapter_overview_cache_xml.html), the region can be configured as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache
    xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
  <cache-server/>
  <region name="exampleRegion" refid="REPLICATE"/>
</cache>
```

I'm using `REPLICATE` for the sake of simplicity, but you should choose the type of region according to your use case.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, so it's an obvious answer. You have to create the region on the server side as well...

Comment: sorry for newbie question but how do you start gfsh with the cache.xml ? when I do so (with 3 or 4 regions pre defined) it's not picking it up.

Comment: You actually don't start gfsh with the cache.xml, this file is used to configure server members. You basically need to use [start server --cache-xml-file=value](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/start.html#topic_3764EE2DB18B4AE4A625E0354471738A). Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I am using SPringBoot2 plus. And trying to use annotation EnableEntityDefinedRegions, but unable to create the region dynamically. Is there an alternative or any other annotation vs gfsh way for Region creation? Please guide.