# Running an Apache Geode cluster in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, apache, geode

I've tried downloading the binaries, and successfully started gfsh, but when I try to start locator or server, the cli just stays forever trying to finalize the startup, adding points to the "progress bar"...like this:

```
Starting a Geode Server in /Users/sezcurra/geode/march-powerful-kite...
.......................................................................
..............................<and goes on for ever>
```

Probably the answer is that it does not run on MAC OSX...

Comment: It would be easier for others to understand the problem if you can provide more technical details like: the properties file, config file, and the exact command you run

Answer (score 0):

No, it runs using the Java Virtual Machine, which is available on OSX. So have you properly [installed Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml)? Also, have you properly [configured the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053709/1964277) xml config file.

Comment: Java is correctly installed. and cache.xml is not mandatory for starting locators or servers. you should be able to start gfsh and do everything from command line. One thing I've noticed is that, even when the command at gfsh keeps waiting for something (don't know what), the locator actually starts....If I open another instance of gfsh and try to connect to port 10334, it connects....